# Django urls on json request

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-views

When making a django request through json as,

```
 var info=id + "##" +name+"##"
 $.post("/supervise/activity/" + info ,[] ,
 function Handler(data,arr) 
  {

  }
```

In urls.py

```
  (r'^activity/(?P<info>\d+)/$, 'activity'),
```

In views,

```
 def activity(request,info):
     print info
```

The request does not go through.`info` is a string.How can this be resolved

Thanks..

Comment: Not enough data. You're regex implies that is numeric string (composed only of digits) is this true? Does it work from browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^activity/(?P<info>\d+)/$` will only match something like 'activity/42/' and the number (in this case 42) will be `info`.

If you appended '##name##' to the url, it will not be recognized.